# grouping array elements in a gsp page grails groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have the following code snippet:

```
<div id="bookmarks" style="height:150px;width:250px; padding-left: 100px;margin-top: -54px;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:scroll;">
    <g:each in="${params['bookmarks'] }" var="bookmark">
        <p><a onclick="seek('${bookmark}');">${bookmark}</a></p>
    </g:each>
</div>
```

However, when I look at the `viewer.gsp`, I see:

```
0
0
:
0
4
:
3
5
,
0
0
:
1
6
:
0
0
,
0
0
:
2
5
:
0
1
```

Instead of the usual `00:04:35` as supposed to be ... How can I format the array `$params['bookmars']` to return me the correct format?

Comment: What are you passing to this gsp from your controller?

Comment: I'm passing a list of time strings, like: `"00:04:35", "00:15:10", "01:30:04"` which represent a specific time in a video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params['bookmarks']` will give you a list for a multi-valued parameter but a `String` if there's only a single value, and `null` if there's no values at all, and `each` on a String iterates over the characters in the string.  So it looks like your `bookmarks` parameter is a single-valued parameter whose value is a comma-separated string `00:04:35,00:16:00,...`, not a multi-valued parameter (i.e. a form submission like `bookmarks=00:04:35&bookmarks=00:16:00&...`).

For parameters that may be multi-valued you can use `params.list('...')`, which guarantees you a list (with zero, one or more than one item as appropriate).

```
<g:each in="${params.list('bookmarks') }" var="bookmark">
```

But if you're stuck with the comma-separated single value then you'll have to split it yourself:

```
<g:each in="${params.bookmarks?.split(/,/)}" var="bookmark">
```

In addition, you probably need to use the relevant `encodeAs...` calls to ensure you get valid JavaScript and HTML:

```
<a onclick="seek('${bookmark.encodeAsJavaScript()}');">${bookmark.encodeAsHTML()}</a>
```